# Google Maps - get all tiles locations around a specific latitude longitude

Tags: google-maps, tiles

I am currently working on an app that requires the ability to temporarily download Google Maps for offline use.

As suggested here [using tileprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206719/how-to-save-google-map-in-android-and-how-to-use-tileprovider) I can render my own tiles for offline use.

Suppose I have the following location lat lng(10,10) and zoom level 2, how can I get all tiles around a distance of 1km near this location .

As shown in this [post](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Lon..2Flat._to_tile_numbers_2) I already know the equation required in order to convert latitude, longitude  to a tile coordinates x,y,z but my problem is I don't know how to figure out what are all the tiles positions around a specific location of a range of 1km for example.

Comment: Google's ToS do not allow this.

Comment: actually it does temporary

Comment: Can you link me to that?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms-20180207 . Nocaching or storage. You will not pre-fetch, cache, index, or store anyContent to be used outside the Service,except that youmay store limited amounts ofContent solely for the purpose of improving the performance of your MapsAPI Implementation due to network latency (and not for the purpose ofpreventingGoogle from accurately tracking usage), and onlyif such storage:
is temporary (and in no event more than 30 days);
secure
does not manipulate or aggregate any part of the Content or Service; and
does not modify attribution in any way.

Comment: like this? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates

Comment: I am not sure that "offline use" falls under "network latency"